# Running multiple clients from same CodeIgniter files

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, include, subdomain

I have to make application in CodeIgniter (CI) that will have same core files for multiple clients.
Every client runs application in his own folder ( using subdomain ) where is his index.php file. In that index.php is included config for that users database ( every user has his own database ). 
I tried to wrap all fiels and application from CI into 1 extra class, and then create instance of that class in every folder of every subdomain. But that didn't work.

Then I have tried to call main index.php from CI folder in every client subdirectory. Here is image of the file structure:
http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/8596/shx8.png

index.php in every subdomain folder was like this:

```
include "../../../application/engine.php";
$app = new Engine();
$app->start();
```

Then when I run that client index.php I get this:

```
    Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the 
following file and correct this: index.php
```

And i did change CI index.php folder paths to:

```
$system_path = '../../../application/engine/system';
$application_folder = '../../../application/engine/application';
```

Then I get following error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\projectX\application\engine\system\core\Utf8.php on line 47
```

As you see, I get error in system\core file, and I am sure I should not edit it.

Utf8.php line 47 is:

```
AND $CFG->item('charset') == 'UTF-8'
```

And that $CFG is defined as:

```
global $CFG;
```

Even if I comment that line, I get next error in other file.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function elapsed_time() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\projectX\application\engine\system\core\Output.php on line 360
```

Output.php line 360 is:

```
$elapsed = $BM->elapsed_time('total_execution_time_start', 'total_execution_time_end');
```

Is there way to fix this problem and finish it this way, or I should have different organisation of files and folders? And how to do it then?

Comment: It is easy to run multiple applications with one system file folder and multiple folder for application. Please visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html Also I use the same principle at www.thephpcode.com to preview the generated website for the users.

Comment: I do know that, but I every application folder is same for every client. So what's the point of having 10-15 folders with same files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like it's said here:http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html

There is no need for wrapping in class.

Leave in root system and application folder, all files from application folder, pack in application/foo/ .

Then create folder in root users/town/client.

Copy index.php from default CI folder, and put it inside users/town/client.

Set paths to the system and application folders and you are good to go.

You can set every client to use application/foo  ( so you get multiple clients to use one same application folder )

Comment: Thx. Will try this and report results.